# Can I get Google Maps to realise DST just ended?

Tags: google-maps

I live in the UK. Last night, DST ended. However, Google Maps is confused and is telling me that trains are running 1 hour early:

[image]

Can I get it to not do this?

Comment: This is more than just an annoying quirk - this means I can see the journey I’m currently on, because it thinks my trains have already left!

Comment: I don't know how fast they react to feedback but they do have a link for that (in the web version)